# Facebook profile image is not displayed with <Image>

Tags: image, react-native

I got an app where I have to show an user profile image.

Some users are logged in by Facebook, so we are saving their Facebook profile image and when I try to render this image with React Native **Image** component, the image is not displayed.

What I got:

```
<Image style={ styles.userImage } source={{uri: "http://graph.facebook.com/{userID}/picture?type=small" }} />
```

And styles:

```
userInfoContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  paddingTop: 30,
  paddingBottom: 30,
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderBottomColor: '#e5e5e5',
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
},

userImage: {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  borderRadius: 50,
  marginBottom: 20,
},
```

I don't know if the problem is that this Facebook image URL doesn't have image extension.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks :)

Comment: Even if the URL doesn't directly point to an image file, there's still an image in there somewhere. Use something like Google Chrome's developer tools to scan network activity when a Facebook image is loaded to see where it's really coming from.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, why do you think the image is not displayed in my React Native app?

Comment: I think it's a source issue. I would try writing a function that given "http://graph.facebook.com/{userID}/picture?type=small" will find the proper location of the image file and pass that as the image source.

Comment: I see. Do you have any clues or any point to start researching about how to get this source location? I don't know how to start. Thanks :)

Comment: did you include the width and height property in the style?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my main post with style information

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the facebook graph url is not the actual url for where that image is stored.  It is a redirect.  There is an issue out on the react-native github which is tracking a similar issue (301 redirect).  It looks like it is partially solved (working for 301's on iOS).

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4940

Some more details about this if you're curious:

Facebook gives you the graph url, but actually stores the image elsewhere on a cdn.  This lets facebook move assets around without breaking the facebook graph url that they document.  The graph url will redirect to the actual url, which means that the graph url returns a 302 (non-permanent redirect).

For example, currently my profile pic would be queried using this url:

https://graph.facebook.com/207537292916369/picture?type=large

But it will redirect (currently) to this actual location:

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/15940479_407531822916914_4834858285678282755_n.jpg?oh=a49a86e0e8042e3df27ce3dfe871b958&oe=59327225

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to remove one set of quotes from the `uri` string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer createbang, but if I remove one set of quotes, I get a syntax error! :/

Comment: That's strange. I copied your code and ran it locally and it only worked with a single set of quotes. Have you tried running the code with the `uri` set to something other than a Facebook image (something you know for sure is public and will work)? For example, `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`

Comment: Sorry! I had a confusion between quotes and curly brackets!! I've edited my main post, those extra quotes was a mistake copying the code to Stackoverflow. In my code there is no extra quotes. thanks!

Comment: I can't see this image you linked there, Error 404.

But I've tried with another image and it is displayed perfectly.

Comment: Okay, so we can isolate the issue to the URL you're providing the `uri` property.

Comment: I think you need to add `/v2.5/` to your url. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101934/discussion-between-createbang-and-jv-lobo).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems lies in the picture url redirection. If you add `&redirect=false` at the end of your url and you use the url fields in the data object shown, the image should show properly.

I don't know the main reason for that but this workaround should help, even though it means writing more code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and easy do this (get user profile's picture) using the Facebook React Native SDK.

1) Import the useful classes for this from **react-native-fbsdk**.

```
import { AccessToken, GraphRequest, GraphRequestManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'
```

2) Implement the Facebook Graph Request in your method, like 'componentDidMount', as an example.

```
try {
  const currentAccessToken = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()

  const graphRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', {
    accessToken: currentAccessToken.accessToken,
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        string: 'picture.type(large)',
      },
    },
  }, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      this.setState({
        picture: result.picture.data.url,
      })
    }
  })

  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(graphRequest).start()
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

3) Use the value of this.state.picture where you need.

```
<Image source={ { uri: this.state.picture } } />
```

I would recommend pass it by props, instead of handling as a stateful resource, but it will depend of your needs.

Comment: this is downloading the image instead of displaying it, check this url `https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10218466988484935&height=200&width=200&ext=1553452039&hash=AeSo-QHBXC1UZzxK`

Comment: Yes, on mine is also downloading image, not showing. How can I expose the profile pic?

Comment: same here, any solution for this?

Comment: @DanteCervantes did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For those showing up to this thread years later like me, the thing that fixed it for me was just changing the Facebook Graph URL from http to https. React Native was able to display it properly after that.